# Select only 1 distinct column - SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table like this in my database

```
orderID| productID | qty
1        5           1
1        2           1
1        6           1
1        4           1
2        9           1
2        5           2
2        6           1
```

I want to output it into my HTML/php page in a similar way to this

```
Order ID:1
Product ID | Qty
5          | 1
2          | 1
6          | 1
4          | 1
Order ID:2
Product ID | Qty
9          | 1
5          | 2
6          | 1
```

Is this even possible to do? I have tried to use DISTINCT but that only outputs 1 row for each orderID. Here is the closest way I have outputted using the ORDER BY statement at the moment but this makes the headers for every row from the database.

```
<?php
    if ($query = "SELECT * FROM productOrders ORDER BY orderID"){
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         {
        ?>                                          

    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Order ID: <?php echo $row['orderID'] ?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['productID'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['qty'] ?></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
<?php
        }
    } 
 ?>
```

Comment: The "normal" approach would be to fetch the data from the table as ordered rows and then do the reformatting at the application level.

Comment: Which RDBMS? The tag "sql" is not very much... And btw: Your nickname is - uhm - not very professional...

Comment: @Shnugo Looking at their code (functions), it's MySQL. Edit: which I added the tag for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah Okay... Reading **does really** help :-)

Comment: Your quantities don't make any sense. How does order ID 2 have 2 quantities of 5?

Comment: @Shnugo Sorry MySQL.

Comment: @JoePhillips thats how many quantities of that product there are on the order. So Order 2 has ordered 2 quantities of product 5.

Comment: @sexpanther OH right. I didn't notice teh qty field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
            <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM productOrders ORDER BY orderID";
                if ($query){
                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                     {
                          $id=$row['orderID'];
                          $sql="SELECT orderID, qty FROM productOrders WHERE orderID=$id";
                          $q=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
                          if(!$q){ echo "error"; }
                           else { while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){

            ?>

                <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order ID <?php echo $id; ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product ID</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row1['productID'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row1['qty'] ?></td>
                </tr>

                </table>


            <?

                       }
          }
                    }
                } 
}
             ?>
```

Comment: Hi @TsvetilinBoynovski thanks for trying but this outputs the headers for each row of the $row1 variables

Answer (score 0):

```
select orderid, productid, sum(qty)
from productOrders
group by orderid, productid
```

which will give you layout of...

```
OrderID | ProductID | Qty
1       | 5         | 1
1       | 2         | 1
1       | 6         | 1
1       | 4         | 1
2       | 9         | 1
2       | 5         | 2
2       | 6         | 1
```

Then just loop through each row and display as needed in PHP